# Subtract integer from time in Google Speadsheet

Tags: time, google-sheets

Let's say I want to calculate my overtime in Google Spreadsheets. I need the function to either convert an integer (10) to a duration (10:00:00), or vice versa, to be able to perform a calculation.

So,

```
=A1 - 8
```

or

```
=A1 - 8:00:00
```

should be converted to

```
10:30:00 - 8:00:00
```

and return

```
02:30:00
```

in order to continue the calculation in another cell.

Comment: There's a time value (duration).

Comment: That works, thank you so much!

Comment: @pnuts How do I use your fracture calculation for any number? For example, I would like to use 40 instead of 8 somewhere else (but the same way as `1/3`... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To convert an integer (or a fraction) representing number of hours to a duration, just divide it by 24. If you put the value 10.5 in A1, then put this formula in B1

```
=A1/24-"08:00:00"
```

And format B1 as Duration, you will get 2:30:00 as the cell value.  The "real" underlying value, though, will be 0.1041666667 which corresponds to 2.5/24th of a day.

Comment: But A1 is always a duration (e.g. 07:30:00, for example).